# How to target css class while working in css modules ?How to add / remove classList element in css modules?

Tags: css-modules, queryselector

I have successfully implemented the code using ***import ./style.CSS*** but in case of css modules how should I target class and how to add or remove that class?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Styles from './Common.module.css'

 constructor(props) {            
      super(props);
      this.Onsignupclick = this.Onsignupclick.bind(this);
      this.Onsigninclick=this.Onsigninclick.bind(this);
    }

    Onsignupclick()
    {
        const container = document.querySelector(".container");
        container.classList.add("signupmode");
    }

    Onsigninclick()
    {
        const container = document.querySelector(".container");
        container.classList.remove("signupmode");
    }
```

<button className={ [Styles.btn , Styles.transparent].join(' ') }id="sign-in-btn" onClick={this.Onsignupclick}>Sign up
<button className={ [Styles.btn , Styles.transparent].join(' ') }id="sign-in-btn" onClick={this.Onsigninclick}>Sign in

On button click, I want to add **signupmode** in CSS module how should I do it?